# How can i convert my seed phrase to private key with python

Tags: ether, web3.py, python, bsc

I need a python script to convert seed phrase to private key is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a basic way to do it:

```
import mnemonic

# This is an example seed phrase
seed_phrase = "letter advice cage absurd amount doctor acoustic avoid letter advice cage above"

# Generate the private key from the seed phrase
private_key = mnemonic.Mnemonic.to_seed(seed_phrase)

# Print the private key
print(private_key)
```